# How does KMeans and Logistic Regression interact with MNIST dataset in Pipeline class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, k-means, gridsearchcv

I am reviewing the "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & Tensorflow" book. One method of classification for the MNIST dataset uses KMeans as a means to preprocess the dataset before using a LogsticRegression model to perform the classification.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X_digits, y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_digits, y_digits, random_state=42)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("kmeans", KMeans(random_state=42)),
    ("log_reg", LogisticRegression(multi_class="ovr", solver="lbfgs", max_iter=5000, random_state=42)),
])

param_grid = dict(kmeans__n_clusters=range(45, 50))
grid_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=3, verbose=2)
grid_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predict = grid_clf.predict(X_test)
```

The output of `grid_clf.predict(X_test)` is in the original digits (digits 0-9) rather than the clusters that are created in the KMeans step in the pipeline. My question is, how is the `grid_clf.predict()` relating its predictions back to the original labels on the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the grid search, the code

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("kmeans", KMeans(n_clusters=45)),
    ("log_reg", LogisticRegression()),
])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

is equivalent to:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=45)
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
new_X_train = kmeans.fit_transform(X_train)
log_reg.fit(new_X_train, y_train)
```

Thus `KMeans` is used to transform the training data. The original data, which has 64 features, is transformed into data with 45 features consisting of distances of the data points to the centers of the 45 clusters. This transformed data, together with the original labels, is then used to fit `LogisticRegression`.

Prediction works the same way: the test data is first transformed by `KMeans` and then `LogisticRegression` is used with the transformed data to predict labels. Thus, instead of

```
predict = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

one could use:

```
predict = log_reg.predict(kmeans.transform(X_test))
```